# UIModalPresentationFormSheet can't change superview background to clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using `UIViewController` with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` presentation style, then I try to present modal to this controller other with current context and Flip Horizontal transition style. But results looks like in an attachment...

I try to set `superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` but any results... also I try to change background color of `superview.layer`, but have on effect

[image]